# Memory Leak in my Python code(lists)

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

So I implemented a DQN code in tensorflow for my research work but while training I found that I have memory leak. After debugging the whole day I found that its the Replay Memory array which causes the memory leak. I have set a limit of 25000 samples for my replay memory list and once it crosses the limit it collects the recent 25000 samples. Here is the code for replay memory dataset collection

```
Replay_Memory.extend(New_sample)

if(len(Replay_Memory)>25000):
    temp=Replay_Memory[len(Replay_Memory)- 25000: len(Replay_Memory)
    Replay_Memory=temp
    del(temp)
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question.

Comment: I mean i need an alternative solution to this.